# Search auto-converts words to tags - but I didn't want to search for the tag!

Tags: discussion, status-bydesign

This is probably more unique to Gaming than SE at large.

I was trying to search for questions about mods in [swtor](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/swtor). Not [mods](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mods), but *[mods](http://www.torhead.com/search/mod)*, the actual items that you can slot into your equipment.

So, simple enough: Enter "[swtor] mods" into search - no results. But wait! The powers of SE have automagically identified that "mods" is a tag, and gone ahead and converted it to [mods]!

Mostly, I think this automatic conversion would be helpful -- if it weren't for the fact that in this instance, it completely changes the intent of my search query.

I'm not quite sure what triggers this conversion, but it'd sure be nice if it didn't happen in this instance.

Is there a way to avoid this auto conversion?

Comment: Ew. The mods tag makes me want to vomit.  It has questions about where to get mods, questions about games which happen to be mods, asking if a mod exists and a technical issue about something that is a mod.  I'm not saying we should get rid of it, but I don't think one tag encompasses all these things... there might be some clean up needed.

Comment: @tzenes open that as a meta topic, tagging takes an extra level of discipline on this site due to the nature of the topic, e.g. http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/2266/allow-tags-to-be-blacklisted-specifically-from-appearing-in-the-html-page-title/3704#3704

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The conversion happens for the top 40 tags on the site:

> Any individual search terms which map directly to the top 40 tags will be auto-converted to tag searches.

From: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/07/stack-overflow-search-now-61-less-crappy/

To avoid it, you can try putting the word in quotes:

```
[swtor] "mods"
```

Which produces: https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=[swtor]+%22mods

Comment: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=[swtor]+%22mods

Comment: Excellent, thanks!