# Do in-game modifications go into the "mods" tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

In games where you can modify your weapons or gear(warframe, Minecraft's Tinker's Construct, LoZ Ocarina of Time's magic arrows), does a question about the functionality of those in-game modifications go into [mods](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mods)?

Comment: Related: http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/3723/lets-talk-about-mods?rq=1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Such questions should **not** get the [mods](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mods) tag; it clearly falls under [category 3 of this meta-post](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4636/sorting-out-the-tagging-mess), a category on which there was broad agreement that should not be used.

In short - since it means different things in different games, it is ill-fitted to be a tag.

This is regardless whether or not [mods](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mods) is useful in the first place (see [this related meta-post](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3723/lets-talk-about-mods)).